# CSS Bootstrap fixed header

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Is it possible in bootstrap to create a table as:

- Fixed headers and scroll-able content like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/)
- The columns need to size proportionaly to the content of the columns (wider/smaller column depanding on content)
- scroll-able x-axis if more columns that can be displayed
- columns have min and max width

So far I found only a solution that would require to know the number of columns to size correctly with a flex approach like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fcdXKE?p=preview) .

```
table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 500px; /* this can vary */
}

table * {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
}

thead {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}

thead > tr, tbody > tr, tfoot > tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

thead, tfoot {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

th, tbody td {
    width: 20%; /* this can vary */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}

tfoot {
    display: inline-block;
}

tfoot td {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I've had the same issue as you. You have to build a table and wrap a table inside. I'll post example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Included is an example of what you might be looking for. I've included how to implement filtering and sorting as well. Keep in mind I just scrapped this together so I haven't had time to test anything, but this is roughly the idea of what you might be looking for?

**HTML File:**

```
                <div class="wrapTable">
                        <table class="head table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td ng-click="sortType = 'id'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                        Id
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'id' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'id' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                        Name
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input ng-model="dataText.id"></td>
                                <td><input ng-model="dataText.name"></td>
                            </tr>                                   
                        </table>
                            <div class="scrollableBody">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse| filter:dataText">
                                            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                    </div>


                    <script>
                    $scope.sortReverse = false;
                    $scope.sortType = 'id'; // set the default sort type
                    $scope.dataText = '';
                    $scope.dataList=....some dynamic JSON data request
                    </script>
```

**CSS File:**

```
.wrapTable {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapTable table { /*set wrap for table*/
    max-width: 10000px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-table;

}

table tr td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px; /*width of each column*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

table.head tr td {
    background: #000000;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
}

.scrollableBody {

    height: 550px;
    min-width: inherit;

    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    position: absolute; /* <-- here is what is important*/
}

.scrollableBody::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0em;
    height: 2em;
}
```

I forgot to mention that inside the wrapTable you can set a fix width and declare scrollable-x if needed.